# How do I specify a repair path from within a mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

How can I specify a repair path for Mongo (v2.2.0) from within the mongo shell?

For example, I could normally run the command:

```
mongod --repair --repairpath /opt/vol2/data
```

How could I specify the repair path if I use the following syntax from within the shell:

```
db.repairDatabase()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `repairDatabase` command will be executed on the database that you are currently connected to and by extension at the path that the current database's data resides.

You can define which database to use by using the `use [dbname]` command from within the mongo shell:

Taken from [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongo-shell/#command-helpers):

> `use <db>`
>   Switch current database to `<db>`. The mongo shell variable
>   db is set to the current database.

Alternatively, you can specify which database to use when [starting the actual shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#core-options). For example, if you wanted to connect to a shell on the `my_db` database that is running on port 27016, you would launch the mongo shell with the following command:

`$ mongo my_db`

To find out which database you are currently using, you can simply type `db` in the shell and you'll get the name of the current database.

Comment: The problem is that my current storage doesn't have enough storage to perform a repairDatabase. I need to specify my external block storage so that the operation can actually complete.

Comment: In this situation you cannot run repair from the shell. You will have to run it from the command line in order to change repairpath. See [repairDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/#dbcmd.repairDatabase).